# SVG is rendered as an inline element or inline-block?

Tags: html, css, svg, dom, browser

A **span** element does not accept **bottom and top margin** being an inline element but an *SVG* does. How it is possible? Are they rendered as **inline-block** elements by browsers?

Comment: Have you... looked? There's decent developer tools in every browser, you should be able to find out.

Comment: @Tomalak, Yeah I've checked it... SVGs are shown `inline` there, but I'm able to apply margin top and bottom 

Comment: I get SVGs as `display: block` from the browser's built-in stylesheet, in both Firefox and Chrome. Not sure where you're looking.

Comment: They're more rendered as if they were a replacement for `<img>` elements, which are `display:inline` but are replaced elements so respect top and bottom margins. But it's a good question. I can't find any spec that says they should be treated that way.

Comment: @Alohci is it this enough to conclude that SVG is a replaced element : *Replaced elements often have intrinsic dimensions: an intrinsic width, an intrinsic height, and an intrinsic ratio.* https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#replaced-element ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Maybe not that ("often have" is too vague IMO), maybe the sentence above it. "Replaced element - An element whose content is outside the scope of the CSS formatting model ..." Unfortunately, the glossary there doesn't define "formatting model". While CSS applies to SVG, it doesn't, as far as I know, affect its layout, which could be meant by formatting model. On the other hand, the same could be said for MathML, but in Firefox that doesn't behave the same way as SVG with respect to padding and margins.

Comment: Then again, the display spec clearly explains how `display:contents` affects the content of svg elements, so CSS can impact on the formatting model/layout to some extent.